# Jquery filter - html elements

Tags: html, jquery

How to filter html elements using Jquery function ?

Below is the html structure. I want to get the value of 2nd span which is inside a tag warpped in a li item ?

````````````````
<li>
<a href="Link2">
<span class="message">Item2</span>
<span class="icon">Icon_2</span> 
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="Link3">
<span class="message">Item3</span>
<span class="icon">Icon_3</span> ----- **How to filter and find this element value based on the message span value ?
</a>
</li>

```````````````
I need a condition like in li if span's value = "Item3", get the below span.icon's value
````````````````

Comment: um..... `li span.icon`

Comment: I have modified my code, sorry. I have other li elements as well, the element values will be the unique ones

Comment: So how are we supposed to know which li? What makes this one special??

Comment: Yes right now there is no class name for the li, the only differentiating factor will be the span's value

Comment: So you have the span's text?

Comment: What do you mean by filter here ? Please can you elaborate more..

Comment: span's text is "Item3". I need a condition like in li element , if there is a span's value = "Item3", get the below span.icon's value

Comment: spans do not have a value.... FYI, those details should be in the question.

Comment: yes I have added now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways to do it. One way is with has and contains.

```js
$("li:has(span.icon:contains('Icon_3'))").addClass("selected")
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="Link2">
      <span class="message">Item2</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="Link3">
      <span class="message">Item3</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And now based on the information you provided.....

```js
var text = $("span.message:contains(Item3) + span.icon").text()
console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="Link2">
      <span class="message">Item2</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="Link3">
      <span class="message">Item3</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or how most people would do it.

```js
var messageElem = $("span.message").filter(function(){ return this.textContent === "Item3" });
var text = messageElem.next("span.icon").text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="Link2">
      <span class="message">Item2</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="Link3">
      <span class="message">Item3</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get the value and not add a class. If the span's value = "Item3", get the below span , that is  span.icon's value

Comment: So alter it.... change it to message, select the span

Comment: Followed the 2nd method and it worked ! Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
$('li span.icon')
```

It should work

Comment: I have modified the code, sorry. I have several li items without id, but I can differentiate them with the span's value. Now how do I filter ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer this, because `:contains()` seeks the matching string and not exact string. That is why, using `filter` is better :)

```js
var choice = $("li span.message").filter(function(){
  return $(this).text().trim() === "Item3";
}).next('span.icon');

//If there is only one item with text "Item3"
console.log(choice.text());

//If there are multiple items 
choice.each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="Link2">
      <span class="message">Item2</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_2</span>
    </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href="Link3">
      <span class="message">Item3</span>
      <span class="icon">Icon_3</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```